# user cannot access folder (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, permissions, filesystem

TLDR: I cannot access a folder even though I am part of the group and the group should have access to it.

So i installed a new service and it created a new folder inside /media called "ftphome".

I then setup the ownership and permissions of this folder by running:

```
sudo chown -R ftp:ftp /media/ftphome
sudo chmod -R u+rwxs,g+rwxs,o-rwx /media/ftphome
```

I then added my primary acct to the ftp group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G ftp tony
```

Looking at /etc/group, the last entry is

```
ftp:x:118:tony
```

But my problem is that when I try to do a simple command like

```
ls -la /media/ftphome
```

I get an error message that says I don't have the necessary permission. I thought adding my acct to the group should've fixed that?

As a test, I created a new folder in /media called "test" and run the same chown/chmod commands from above and I still don't have access to this test folder.

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The user doesn't have permissions to access the parent directory (/media)? Might be best to create a directory that needs to be shared inside /home).

Comment: What does command `groups` say? users don't actually inherit the new group membership until a new login shell is started

Comment: you have to write `ls /media/ftphone/` to see what is in the folder---note the trailing /.  with out the / asks for the information on the folder, which you don't have permission to access.